# jenkinsfile if statement not using wildcard statement

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Im trying to work out the correct syntax based on the below if statement in a jenkinsfile, however its not passing the wildcard as expected and trying to match the syntax including the wildcard symbol:

```
stage('stage c') {
  steps {
    container('tf-jenkins') {
      script {
      sh """
      if [[ \$(gcloud container clusters list --format='value(name)' --project ${project_id} --filter=d-kcl-${short_region} ) = *d-kcl* ]]; then
        echo "cluster already exists, progressing to application deployment"
      else
        echo "no cluster found, a new cluster needs to be deployed"
      fi
      """
      }
    }
```

With the above the stage block, the following is returned:

```
+ gcloud container clusters list '--format=value(name)' --project prpject-id '--filter=d-kcl'
+ '[[' paas-gcp-d-kcl-euwe2 '=' '*paas-gcp-d-kcl*' ]]
+ echo 'no cluster found, a new cluster needs to be deployed'
no cluster found, a new cluster needs to be deployed
```

when running in a normal shell this works as expected but not in the jenkinsfile.

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using groovy code instead of a shell script.

```
stage('stage c') {
 steps {
   container('tf-jenkins') {
     script {
         def commandOutput = sh (
                                  script: "gcloud container clusters list --format='value(name)' --project ${project_id} --filter=d-kcl-${short_region}", 
                                  returnStdout: true,
                                  label: "Check if container exists"
                               ).trim()

        if(commandOutput.contains("d-kcl")){
            echo "cluster already exists, progressing to application deployment"
        } else{
           echo "no cluster found, a new cluster needs to be deployed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```